# How to configure hybrid integrated GPU with GPU?

Tags: amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

Hey guys I'm building a new machine for the upcoming MWO Mechwarrior Online video game running on the Crysis 3 engine. It says minimum requirements are 512mb video memory. I have a standalone Radeon X1300PRO 256mb DDR2 discreet GPU that was bought several years ago. I know this will not be enough to run the game. However, I know LucidLogix Virtu technology allows integrated graphics and standalone discreet cards to work efficiently together. I plan on buying the Intel 3rd gen Ivy Bridge Core i7-3770K processor with Intel HD4000 embedded graphics. I will also be using 2x4gb Patriot Viper Xtreme low latency 2400mHz memory sticks to support the onboard graphics. The Asus Maximus V Gene motherboard I'm going to use also has embedded graphics but I'm not going to bother with them.

My question is, is there a way to configure the BIOS to use the HD4000 Intel graphics with the Radeon X1300Pro to run MWO on Crysis 3 engine on minimal visual settings?  I know Intel and Radeon graphics aren't supposed to work together. It's SLI or CrossfireX but not 1 radeon working togeher with an nVidia card. Right?

Or am I better off just selling the X1300Pro for whatever I can get for it and buy a cheap standalone discreet GPU?  Do I need a card that is Direct X11 compatible?  Please help I used to be really into computers and gaming but have fallen out a few years and now I am absolutely dying to play my favorite series of all time, Mechwarrior.

Comment: Probably better off buying a new card. Performance of combining onboard and a card is lackluster if you can even get it to work. In this scenario I doubt you would be able to.

Comment: Simplest answer, ebay old card, buy new card.  You'll shoot your eye out trying to get onboard to work with discreet, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to solve a problem that need not exist in the first place. You would be better served for your intended use (gaming) by not going with a low-latency RAM (it's all much the same these days) and choosing a slightly-less beasty CPU and putting resources towards a new video card.

Trees, forests etc.

Your 256mb card will also be hindered by a lack of RAM. Most new performance cards have 1GB+ available these days. It uses the RAM to cache textures so more is better and typically means less IO thrashing occurs during game time.